# Change module location

Tags: 8, composer

Somehow while converting my D8 site to a composer based site, I ended up with the modules in the `sites/modules` folder as well as in the `sites/modules/contrib` folder. When I delete the module folders from `sites/modules` I get the WSOD. Composer says there is nothing to update, so the modules within the `contrib` folder are OK.

How do I get the system to recognize the modules in the contrib folder over the modules folder, so they can be deleted?

Comment: Try deleting the modules folder ones and then with Drush do `drush cr`. If you don't have drush, then empty/truncate all Cache tables in the DB.

Comment: This seemed to work on first glance, but as soon as you navigate away from the page, there's PHP errors thrown.